# assigning a delegate with no signature to an EventHandler - how does this work?

Tags: c#, delegates, event-handling

If I do this line:

```
EventHandler foobar = new EventHandler(fooMethod);
```

fooMethod must be a method with the following signature:

```
public void fooMethod(object obj, EventArgs args){}
```

Makes sense to me. However, this code works just fine:

```
EventHandler foo = delegate { };
```

How is this? I would have thought that I needed to do this:

```
EventHandler foo = delegate(object obj, EventArgs arg) { };
```

The above line does work btw. I am simply confused as to how I can assign an "empty" delegate to an EventHandler.

Thanks to anyone who can illuminate me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Anonymous methods* (the way of constructing delegates via `delegate { /* body */ }` have two forms:

```
delegate (parameter list)
{
    // body
}
```

and

```
delegate
{
    // body
}
```

The second form can be converted to any delegate type which doesn't use `out` parameters (IIRC - it may not cope with `ref` either) assuming the return values match the return type of the delegate type. For example:

```
Func<int> foo = delegate { return 5; };
```

This form is handy if you don't care about the parameters. Note that it increases the number of delegate types the expression can be converted to, which can confuse overloading:

```
new Thread(delegate { Console.WriteLine("Error - ambiguous"); });
new Thread(delegate() { Console.WriteLine("Fine - ThreadStart"); });
new Thread(delegate(object state) {
    Console.WriteLine("Fine - ParameterizedThreadStart");
});
```

Comment: Just verified that second form can handle `ref` parameters, but not `out`. That is kind of interesting, because I thought the CLR only supported `ref` parameters and `out` parameters were just a C# construct built on top of `ref` parameters.

Comment: @Harry: The important difference is what C# guarantees about what happens to an out parameter within the method. The C# compiler *could* generate code to assign it a default value, I suppose - but I think it would be better not to.